# Eclipse Configuration to debug in Program Files

Tags: eclipse

My company has a windows app that installs to c:\Program Files, as usual. We have discovered that running as a regular user prevents a necessary function from happening. The only way to successfully perform these functions is to run as administrator, but that is an undesirable solution for our customers.

When I attempt to debug in Eclipse in order to trap the specific issue, our app fails because access to other directories in Program Files is denied. Running from a user-defined directory won't allow me to reproduce the specific error that we're seeing our customers have after our product install. Is there anyway to configure an Eclipse app to execute as a normal user in the Program  Files directory?

Answer (score 0):

One way to sidestep issues related to the way the program is being launched, or peculiarities of its runtime environment such as permissions at the operating system level, is to use **remote debugging**, i.e. launch your program as a user would, but instruct the JVM to open an additional tcp port for remote debugging, which eclipse can use to connect to (and debug) this application. This even works if the application is running on a different computer.

A somewhat dated, but still mostly accurate, remote debugging tutorial can be found at

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. However, I'm still not getting the desired results. My normal app executing in Program Files fails in the function, but after adding remote debugging to Eclipse, it succeeds. What I did was export my RCP app as an executable into program files with the debug parameters set, started my Eclipse instance in a remote debug configuration as a server, and then kicked off my program files version. It connected to the breakpoint I set in Eclipse fine, but didn't fail, which leads me to believe it's still not running from program files, as I need it to in order to fail.

Comment: I figured it out. I did use the remote debugger as you suggested, but I had to change everything in my program files execute directory to be owned by SYSTEM to mimic the same behavior. Thanks for your help